# How can I parse the size of the DNS section of a packet using scapy?

Tags: python, scapy

I am trying to only get the amount of bytes in the DNS section of the packet. I have imported a pcap file and can iterate through each packet I am just confused since I  don't see any way online to just get the amount of bytes of the  DNS. Thanks!

[Wireshark Cap Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSsTx.png)

In the above image how am I able to only get the bytes highlighted

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Scapy, that's `len(packet[DNS])`